# list size is captured only in Debug mode

Tags: java, selenium, debugging, automation, ui-automation

Highlighted in bold i.e totallist captures a value 0. But when I run in Debug mode, correct values gets captured. serviceX is common for all the dropdowns and thus I am assigning all findelements into a list and then selecting a value matching the value from excel.

private By serviceX = By.xpath("//div/ul/li[@class='datixSelectOption' or @class='datixSelectOption datixSelectOption-hover']");

public void createIncident(Map dataMap) throws InterruptedException
{

```
    //Block to select Who or what from drop down
    String val1 =(String) dataMap.get("WhoorWhat");
    isElementPresent(whoOrWhat).click();
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     List<WebElement> listElements=getWebElements(serviceX);
     int totallist =  listElements.size();
        **System.out.println(totallist);**
     for (WebElement li : listElements) 
     {
        System.out.println(li.getText());
        
         if (li.getText().equals(val1)) { 
             li.click(); 
             break;
             }
        
        
    }
     listElements.clear();
    
    //Block to select specific service
    if(isElementPresent(specificService).isDisplayed()) 
    {
        String service  = (String) dataMap.get("SpecificService"); 
        String [] serviceArr =  service.split("-");
        System.out.println(serviceArr[0]);
        System.out.println(serviceArr[1]);
        getSpecificService().sendKeys(serviceArr[0]);
    
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<WebElement> serviceList = getWebElements(serviceX);
        int totalServiceList =  serviceList.size();
        System.out.println(totalServiceList);
        for (int j = 0;j<=totalServiceList; j++) {
             String serviceName = serviceList.get(j).getText();
             System.out.println(serviceName);
            
 
             if(serviceName.contains(serviceArr[1])) {
            System.out.println(serviceName);
            serviceList.get(j).click();
            break;
        }
        }
        serviceList.clear();
    }
            
          
    //Block to select Where did this incident occur? from drop down 
        getIncidentOccur().click();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<WebElement> incidentOccur=getWebElements(serviceX);

        String occurPlace =(String) dataMap.get("IncidentOccur");
        System.out.println(occurPlace);
        for (WebElement li1 : incidentOccur) {
            System.out.println(li1.getText());
            
             if (li1.getText().equals(occurPlace)) { 
                 li1.click(); 
                 break;
                 }
            
            
        }
        incidentOccur.clear();
        
    //Block to select location from text dropdown

        String loc =  (String) dataMap.get("Location"); 
        String [] locationArr =  loc.split("-");
        getLocationField().sendKeys(locationArr[1]);
    
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<WebElement> listLocations = getWebElements(serviceX);
        int totalList =  listLocations.size();
        //System.out.println(totalList);
        for (int j = 0;j<=totalList; j++) {
             String locationName = listLocations.get(j).getText();
             //System.out.println(locationName);
            
 
             if(locationName.contains(locationArr[0])) {
             //System.out.println(locationName);
                 listLocations.get(j).click();
                 break;
        }
        }
        listLocations.clear();

        
        //Block to select Principal incident type
        String principalIncident  = (String) dataMap.get("PrincipalIncident"); 
        getPrincipalIncidentType().sendKeys(principalIncident);
    
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<WebElement> principalList = getWebElements(serviceX);
        int totalPrincipalList =  principalList.size();
        for (int j = 0;j<=totalPrincipalList; j++) {
             String principalName = principalList.get(j).getText();
             System.out.println(principalName);
            
 
             if(principalName.contains(principalIncident)) {
                 principalList.get(j).click();
            break;
        }
        }
        principalList.clear();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Output on console for totallist = 0 and exception thrown - org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: service_id_title (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval). Execution control is moving to webelement -Specific Service.

Comment: Usually, if something is catched with WebDriver **only** in debug mode it means that the element just didn't have enough time to appear on UI in a normal mode but in debug mode it takes more time or you just hit breakpoints and it gives additional time for UI to update / draw elements.